# SharePoint listview color change on checkbox click

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint list and I have changed the row color by adding this piece of code in CEWP.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-alternating
{
background-color: White;
}
</style>
```

Now when I click on the checkbox at the left of the row, the item color is very dark and the letters are not viewable.

Is there any way to change the color of them too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
<style type="text/css">

TR.s4-itm-selected > TD {
    COLOR: pink !important;
background-color:green;
}
TR.s4-itm-selected:hover > TD {
    COLOR: pink !important;
    background-color:green;
}
tr.s4-itm-selected a, tr.s4-itm-selected:hover a{
COLOR: pink !important;
}</style>
```

Please remember that you will have to click on the checkbox to see the change in text colours
Cheers
Truez

Comment: you mean like a new line of code so my css will look like this `background-color: White;color:pink`. If yes, I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply. Should my script look like this? `<style type="text/css">tr.s4-itm-selected > td, tr.s4-itm-selected:hover > td { Color:pink; } </style>`

Comment: A common practice is to place a .css file in the style library and just put a `<style>` tag with a reference to that file in the CEWP.

Comment: I can see the text color changes, but it there a way to change the background color of the row when we click the checkbox?

Comment: @learner your question only asks to change the colour of the text, therefore I've provided the answer, People do not come to this forum to do other peoples work. I will update the answer but in future ask for what you want do not ask additional information in the same post

Comment: @Truezplaya - I'm sorry to bother, can you help me solve this?

Comment: @learner I have it's updated in my post notice I've added background-colour:green please mark as answer if this resolves your initial issue

Comment: @Truezplaya - I tried the script and background color doesn't change.